# Get started with QPID

Tags: c#, java, windows, apache, qpid

Could anyone share some links on how to get started using QPID?

I have checked out http://qpid.apache.org/ and I have managed to start the Java QPID broker, but I don't know where to go from here.

It would be great if someone had a sample app or two to use the broker and send messages to each other, in Java or C#.

If not, maybe someone could point me in the right direction and give me some links or documentation on how to get started with QPID.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this example for C# and WCF: [QPID WCF samples](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/qpid/trunk/qpid/wcf/samples/)

Comment: no longer functioning